# Is a "bisschen" a "little bite"?

Tags: etymology

I've always interpreted "bisschen" as just meaning "a little".

Does it come from the diminuative of "der Biss" (the bite)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [German Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bisschen) writes about its linguistic origin with reference to *Johann Christoph Adelung: Grammatisch-kritisches Wörterbuch der hochdeutschen Mundart*:

> entstanden aus der Diminutivform des Substantivs Biss; es bedeutet somit also:
>   Gerade soviel, wie man auf einmal (mit einem Biss) abbeißt.
>   Adelung stellt den Wandel der Diminutivform „Bißchen“ (Ein Bißchen Brot
>   / Ein Bißchen Wein) zum Nebenwort „bischen“ dar

So, it comes from the diminutive form of „der Biss“: das Bisschen = *little bite*

Comment: or... "little bit".  wow!

Comment: Yes: the English *bit* is also derived (in around the 16th century, according to the OED) from *bite*, in the sense of a bite of food.

Answer (score 7):

Actually both meaning, and usage of *"ein bisschen"* is very similar to the English *"a bit"* (vs. *"bit/bite"*). Likewise we also know the *"little bit"* in German: *"ein kleines bisschen"*. Note that it originated form a diminutive of *"Biss"* but it is not used as a noun in this context, seen by the lowercase spelling in its present usage as a pronoun. When used as a noun *"ein Bisschen"* in the meaning of a little bite we have to spell it with an uppercase initial.

Both the English *[bit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bit)*, and the German *[Biss](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=biss)* share the same etymologic root with the Indo-European *bheid-* (splitting something with an axe). Interestingly in Swiss German *"Mundart"* the meaning of *[Biss](http://www.idiotikon.ch/Register/faksimile.php?band=4&spalte=1696)* was a wedge.

Regionally there is quite some variation for *bisschen*:

> bissel
>   bisserl
>   bissle
>   chli biss
>   *...and many more*

Comment: I'm Swiss German and I can't say *Biss* has the meaning of *wedge* to me.

Comment: @Tass: thank you for the note - I found this in the *Schweizerisches Idiotikon* linked to above. This *Mundart* meaning (like others) are sadly in the process of getting lost over time.